# split two tags and append them separately in bs4 python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a `TR[2]` which is dynamic and I try to get it like this:

```
self.soup.select("#detail > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)")
```

I want all `td[3]` in it which they are dynamic in this way:
they may have only string or both string and `<a href>` now I want to split the string in some variable and "string" of that `<a>` tag in another but the thing that matter is that `td` which has no `<a>` I want it to append "None" because both variables should have the same length and index in order to "zip" them correctly for further use.
here is some example :

```
<td class='bolt'>
  "the text I want"
  <br>
  <a href='Javascript:void(0);'>the other text i want</a>
</td>
```

which when they are appending to var should look like this:

```
event = ["the text I want"]
vessel = ["the other text i want"]
```

and another 'possible' td:

```
<td class='bolt'>
   "another string we need"
</td>
```

and the final result :

```
event = ["the text I want","another string we need"]
vessel = ["the other text i want", None(or empty),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be one or two text nodes (as described in question), you can use

```
vessel = []
event = []
for td in self.soup.select("#detail > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)"):
    event.append([i.strip() for i in td.strings if i.strip()][0])
    vessel.append(([i.strip() for i in td.strings if i.strip()] + [None])[1])

print(event)
['"the text I want"', '"another string we need"']
print(vessel)
['the other text i want', None]
```

Let me know in case there might be more complex cases